# Connection to the wrong access point

Tags: wireless

I have a wifi mesh. Meaning, I have two AP with the same SSID. One AP is in the basement the other on the ground floor. The laptop seems to always connect to the basement AP even when the ground floor has a much stronger signal. I tried to forget the network and reconnect: the laptop shows the signal is strong but when it connects it shows it as weak again.

How can I "convince" it to connect to the right AP?

Using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using on your laptop?  Also, have you tried splitting your 2.4GHz and 5GHz SSIDs into 2 separate ones?  Sometimes making those separate helps a ton in signal strength so that the device trying to connect to it doesn't have to keep switching between 2.4 and 5 automatically.

Comment: 20.04. The 2.4 and 5 SSIDs are split, but that is not the issue. I have two 2.4 AP with the same ssid and the laptop doesn't choose the optimal one

Comment: Do you get the same bad signal if you turn off the mesh point closest to your laptop and it is connecting only to the one further away?  The signal selection is handled by the driver itself and no settings in Ubuntu that I am aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Networkmanager has a priority setting for connections.

It is hidden though. Use `nm-connection-editor` and it will show a popup with wireless options. Go to your connection, "general" and there is a priority option.

The higher the number the least likely it is picked out of all possible options. I have mine set as ...

- Home private network
- At work private network
- Home Ziggo public network over my home router
- Ziggo public network (for when I am outside)
- Wireless hotspot over phone (that one is metered so emergency only).

This does require you to have both APs identify with a different name. If those are the same you should activate 2.4Ghz on one and 5Ghz on the other and set the router to use a name for each.

If the wireless network name (SSID) is the same for both APs, the basic service set identifier (BSSID) should be unique since BSSIDs identify access points. You can set these in Network manager at the Identity tab.

Set a BSSID for both APs. The two APs will then show up as two different networks with the same name. listed twice and NetworkManager will have a better chance of choosing the strongest signal PLUS you can put a priority on each.

- check "client roaming threshold" in your APs. If supported those need to be identical
- DHCP IP leasing for clients needs to be identical as well.

Priority setting:

[image]

SSID:

[image]

Comment: I have two AP with the same SSID

Comment: @Raffa, but I don't want to statically select. I want the best to be selected according to the signal strength at any given time